# Post to ReCAPTCHA

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, recaptcha

I am trying to post to recapture from c# code.

```
        var data = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "privatekey", "my key" },
            { "remoteip ", "" },
            { "challenge ", model.recaptcha_challenge_field },
            { "response ", model.recaptcha_response_field }
        };

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {

            var response = client.UploadValues("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", data: data);

            var result = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(response);

        }
```

When I do this result is returning

```
false invalid-request-cookie
```

Do I need to set the remote IP? What else could be going wrong?

**Update**

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify says the error means:

> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

The value of the html on page is as follows:

```
<INPUT id=recaptcha_challenge_field value=03AHJ_VusdI2SY_P2iM3VICgLmOw-7CE7F6zmOwvwfya4L8Jeiok_rCwVmHFJwJHxlelhp8By_QTA7SNF58fwijij5rxBLqgpoI3nuWy6S0HGL7U7lk_35aazPfaMyVwbeWuWJyxJ0DqjwDwrByD4AY70O0qlaTnCUxQ type=hidden name=recaptcha_challenge_field />
```

In the object I post back it is as follows:

`“recaptcha_challenge_field=03AHJ_VusdI2SY_P2iM3VICgLmOw-7CE7F6zmOwvwfya4L8Jeiok_rCwVmHFJwJHxlelhp8By_QTA7SNF58fwijij5rxBLqgpoI3nuWy6S0HGL7U7lk_35aazPfaMyVwbeWuWJyxJ0DqjwDwrByD4AY70O0qlaTnCUxQ&recaptcha_response_field=re`merh+much"

and when i get it on the server the value is

```
03AHJ_VusdI2SY_P2iM3VICgLmOw-7CE7F6zmOwvwfya4L8Jeiok_rCwVmHFJwJHxlelhp8By_QTA7SNF58fwijij5rxBLqgpoI3nuWy6S0HGL7U7lk_35aazPfaMyVwbeWuWJyxJ0DqjwDwrByD4AY70O0qlaTnCUxQ
```

So if we put all 3 value side by side we have:

```
03AHJ_VusdI2SY_P2iM3VICgLmOw-7CE7F6zmOwvwfya4L8Jeiok_rCwVmHFJwJHxlelhp8By_QTA7SNF58fwijij5rxBLqgpoI3nuWy6S0HGL7U7lk_35aazPfaMyVwbeWuWJyxJ0DqjwDwrByD4AY70O0qlaTnCUxQ 
03AHJ_VusdI2SY_P2iM3VICgLmOw-7CE7F6zmOwvwfya4L8Jeiok_rCwVmHFJwJHxlelhp8By_QTA7SNF58fwijij5rxBLqgpoI3nuWy6S0HGL7U7lk_35aazPfaMyVwbeWuWJyxJ0DqjwDwrByD4AY70O0qlaTnCUxQ 
03AHJ_VusdI2SY_P2iM3VICgLmOw-7CE7F6zmOwvwfya4L8Jeiok_rCwVmHFJwJHxlelhp8By_QTA7SNF58fwijij5rxBLqgpoI3nuWy6S0HGL7U7lk_35aazPfaMyVwbeWuWJyxJ0DqjwDwrByD4AY70O0qlaTnCUxQ
```

The recapture on the page is being generated by calling the following:

```
Recaptcha.create("pub key",
    "myDiv",
    {
        theme: "clean",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
  );
```

Comment: I bet the request cookie is invalid!

Answer (score 4):

You have left spaces in remoteip,challenge and response parameters.
It should be

```
var data = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "privatekey", "my key" },
            { "remoteip", "192.168.1.111" },
            { "challenge", model.recaptcha_challenge_field },
            { "response", model.recaptcha_response_field }
        };
```

Also IP address is required but the current error you are getting is because of the leading spaces in your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The reCAPTCHA specification clearly states that the "remoteip" parameter is indeed **required**:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify